# Driving in a EU country with an International Driving Permit of a Non EU country as EU resident

Tags: driving-license

I have a question regarding an International Driving Permit. Currently I live in Belgium as a resident. I still have a valid driver's license from my native country with a valid international driving permit. I will be travelling to Norway and was wondering if I can use it to drive there. I understand I cannot drive in Belgium with it as I am a resident, but does this apply to another EU member state which I will visit as a tourist?

Comment: EU law applies to European driving licenses and define many rules regarding mutual recognition but says nothing about licenses from outside the EEA. It's still up to each state to define the rules regarding their recognition, the need to hold an international driving permit, etc. Rules like the one forbidding you to drive in Belgium with your license therefore generally refer to residence in a specific country, not in the EU as a whole. Beyond that, whether you are allowed to drive in Norway would depend on their rules regarding licenses from your country of origin.

Comment: Also note that Norway is not an EU country as well (it's part of the EEA though)

Answer (score 1):

As is noted by @Gala, [EU driving licences](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/vehicles/driving-licence/driving-licence-recognition-validity/index_en.htm) are recognised throughout the EU. Norway is EEA, not EU.

According to the [Statens Vegvesen, the Norwegian Public Roads Administration](https://www.vegvesen.no/en/driving+licences/About+Driving+licences/foreign-driving-licences-in-norway/issued-outside-the-eu-eea/driving-in-norway)

> **Driving with driving licences issued in non-EU/EEA c**ountries
>
> You may use your driving licence from any country for up to three months, during both temporary and permanent stays in Norway. The driving licence must be valid, and the Norwegian age requirements must be met.
>
> An international driving licence is required as a supplement to some driving licences. If you are not sure if your driving licence can be used in Norway without additional documentation, we recommend that you get an international driving licence pursuant to the Geneva or Vienna conventions (grey booklet with white pages) before you come to Norway.
>
> Persons who work for travelling circuses or fun fairs, and who have valid work permits, may use their national driving licence in Norway for up to six months.

Refer to [Foreign driving licences in Norway](https://www.vegvesen.no/en/driving+licences/About+Driving+licences/foreign-driving-licences-in-norway) as to how it applies to those with EU/EEA licences.

> In Norway, separate rules apply for driving licences issued in EU/EEA countries and driving licences issued in non-EU/EEA countries. There is also a difference between the right to drive in Norway with the foreign driving licence, and the right to exchange it for a Norwegian driving licence.